# Using HTACCESS rewrite rule I can't modify my URL Structure of my website

Tags: php, .htaccess

My Host Name -> ps129202.dreamhostps.com
domain -> http://www.uastudents.com/

My Url structure : one is /innerpage.php?lang=3&pageid=6&name=SELECT%20PROGRAM AND other one /index.php?lang=3

Here is my *.htaccess code*:

```
RewriteEngine On     
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/images/(.*)$ images/$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/css/(.*)$ css/$2
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ innerpage.php?lang=$1&pageid=$2&name=$3
```

My url Structure is domain/innerpage.php?lang=3&pageid=6&name=SELECT%20PROGRAM and 
domain/index.php?lang=3
Desired url is : domain/3/6/SELECT%20PROGRAM and domain/3
I really puzzled can't run it anyway.. how Can I solve ??? Any other process there ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ innerpage.php?lang=$1&pageid=$2&name=$3 [L]
```

Also, [test your regexes here](http://regexpal.com/), the one for innerpage.php would never work, as "SELECT%20PROGRAM" has special characters in it, not a-zA-Z.

Comment: Plus it has `.php` at the end and server may try to find such file

Comment: @user4035 the `.php` will not trigger a script with mod_rewrite, as Apache first processes redirects, only then tries to find real files ;)